# Z-order bug in Jobs: Company logo and buttons appear on top of "update status" modal in job listings

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, design

The underlying company logo and buttons appear on top of the modal in the job listings.

To reproduce:

1. Go to https://stackoverflow.com/jobs
2. Type something in the search bar
3. Press enter (important)
4. Then click on "update status"

[image]

This happened on Firefox.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has been fixed - thank you for reporting this.